# Is XML Schema xs:alternative equivalent available in JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

Is it possible to use alternatives in JSON Schema? In XSD this is doable using `xs:alternative` element.

For example see: [How to use alternatives in XML Schema 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593284/how-to-use-alternatives-in-xml-schema-1-1)

---

UPDATE 1:

This is a sample JSON I would like to describe using JSON schema:

```js
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "param1": "value"
    },
    {
      "type": "extended",
      "param1": "value",
      "param2": "blah"
    }
  ]
}
```

Requirements:

- `actions` may have any number of items
- `basic` actions must contain `param1` property
- `extended` actions must contain `param1` and `param2` properties

Comment: I answered with a general solution, although if you provide a concrete example it might be easier to assess a solution.

Comment: @jruizaranguren I've added a concrete example as requested.

Comment: From your example you have a base type (with a single required param1) and an optional param2. You can enforce this just by putting param1 and param2 in properties, and establish param1 to required. For more complex examples please review the keywords provided in the answer.

Comment: No, param2 is not optional. That's the whole point: when type=extended param2 is required. Anyway, thank you for the hints, I will check oneOf and other options.

Comment: And is param1 the same param1 in both types? I mean, there exist some short of inheritance?

Comment: No, they are different although for some kinds of type they may look the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar mechanism since Draft04 with nicer semantics: oneOf, anyOf, allOf and not, keywords.

- oneOf: enforce a given element to satisfy only one of a list of schemas.
- anyOf: must satisfy at least one of a list of schemas.
- allOf: must satisfy all provided schemas in list.
- not: must not satisfy a given schema.

Assuming you are looking for an exclusive "alternative", this would be an example of json-schema using oneOf:

```
{
    "actions" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : {
            "oneOf" : [{
                    " $ref " : "#/definitions/type1 "
                }, {
                    " $ref " : "#/definitions/type2 "
                }
            ]

        }

    },
    " definitions " : {
        " type1 " : {
            " type " : " object ",
                        "properties": {
                                  "param1":{"type":"string"}
                        },
                        "required":["param1"]
        },
        " type2 " : {
            " type " : " object ",
                         "properties": {
                                  "param2":{"type":"string"},
                                  "param3":{"type":"string"}
                        },
                         "required":["param2","param3"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising although when I tried to validate a simple object with "param1" and "param3" it was validated successfully (btw: I added `additionalProperties:false` to both type definitions). Though I am not sure if this is a schema or validator issue. I used http://jsonschemalint.com/

Comment: Yes, it is. jsonschemalint uses draft03. My schema is draft04.

Comment: BTW: I would appreciate if you could update your answer with statement that JSON Schema draft04 is required to use oneOf syntax. Thanks!