# json schema for dynamic properties that change depending on a "type"

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to build a json schema that represents the following resource:

```
X resource:
{
  "type" : "{some enum of types}",
  <some list of properties that depend on the enum>
}
```

Here are some (not real) examples to illustrate:

```
{
  "type" : "car",
  "color" : "red",
  "style" : "van"
}

{
  "type" : "plane",
  "color" : "white",
  "aisle" : "double"
}
```

As you can see, the `aisle` property only applies when the `type` is `plane`, and the `style` property only applies when the `type` is `car`. The property `color` is common.

I have been able to get something like this:

```
X schema:
{
  "$schema" : ...
  ...
  "properties" : {
    "type" : {...},
    "color" : {...}.
    "sub_properties" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "oneOf" : [ ... ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this only applies to a property, `sub_properties` of `X`. That is, the following json:

```
{
  "type" : "car",
  "color" : "red",
  "sub_properties" : {
    "style" : "van"
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to "lift" the `oneOf` so that it applies to the properties of `X` directly.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please post your code and data sample from which you want desired output.

Answer (score 0):

From your text I can understand two different things:

- If you have an enum, and want to define types that restrict the values of the enum, your only choice is to use an enum property, and use it to be able to select schemas by value. [as it is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131).
- If you just want to have alternative schemas for X, you can define directly:

  "X Schema": {"oneOf":[{"id":"schema1"},{"id":"schema2"}]}

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use this? Does this mean I have to define two separate schemas and refer to them? I'm looking at section 7.2 of the schema4 spec and its not quite clear to me how to make it real.

Comment: Have a look to this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724896/is-xml-schema-xsalternative-equivalent-available-in-json-schema/26788918#26788918